# Django - Update View, creating new Objects instead of updating,

Tags: python, django

I am trying to use Update view in django, in the simplest manner, but it is not being updated, rather a new object of the model is being created in the database. I have done the same thing for another model Track, and its working fine. I feel it might be something trivial that might be causing the problem.

I am modifying the PK of the model here. Could this be the reason?

**View:**

```
    from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView
    from musictracker.models.datamodels.Genre import Genre

    class EditGenre(UpdateView):

        model = Genre
        template_name = "editGenre.html"
        fields = ['name']
```

**Template:**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} {% load addcss %} {% block content %}
<div id="regContainer">
    <ul>
        <!-- {% if form.errors %} {{form.errors}} {% endif %} -->
    </ul>
    <div class="form-group">
        <form method="post" action="">
            {% csrf_token %} 

            {% for field in form %}

            <label class="control-label" for="form-control input-sm">{{field.label_tag }}</label>
            <br /> {{field|addcss:"form-control input-sm"}}
            <br /> 

            {% endfor %}
            <input type="submit" id="register" value="Edit Genre" class="btn btn-default">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**URLS.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

''' View Imports '''
from views import TrackList
from views import AddTrack
from views import TrackDetail
from views import EditTrack

from views import GenreList
from views import GenreDetail
from views import AddGenre
from views import EditGenre


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^tracks/', TrackList.as_view(),name='all-tracks'),
    url(r'^addTrack/', AddTrack.as_view(),name='add-tracks'),
    url(r'^editTrack/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)', EditTrack.as_view(),name='edit-track'),
    url(r'^track/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)', TrackDetail.as_view(),name='track'),

    url(r'^genres/', GenreList.as_view(),name='all-genres'),
    url(r'^addGenre/', AddGenre.as_view(),name='add-genre'),
    url(r'^editGenre/(?P<pk>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)', EditGenre.as_view(),name='genre'),
    url(r'^genre/(?P<pk>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)', GenreDetail.as_view(),name='genre'),
]
```

**Model:**

```
class Genre(models.Model):
    '''
    This is a model for Genres
    '''

    name = models.CharField(max_length=20,primary_key=True,editable=True)
    songcount = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('genre', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Comment: Why have you set the `name` field as the primary key? Don't do that.

Comment: I know i should have made an auto increment as a PK and the name Unique. I am just trying things. But it should still work, shouldn't it? Or is the PK not editable here/or do we need to configure something to make it editable

Comment: If your PK is an editable field, and you edit it, then Django has no way of knowing that a save is an update rather than a create.

Comment: I mad ethe field editable. using Editable true in the models. But it still is creating new objects, copying the value of other field.(songcount)

Answer (score 4):

Well, as other folks said in comments, your view creates new object instead of update because you have editable primary key.

You see, undercover `UpdateView` creates form for your model and calls `save` on that form.

It's the `save` method of `BaseModelForm` which operates `self.instance` attribute. And if instance isn't being found by pk, new one will be created. So I suggest you to recreate your model with uneditable primary key and leave name as just simple char field.

Comment: Well, thats an option. But is there no way one can do this? except for maybe writing own sql queries. 
So something like this happens ->
Object fetched by Form
Object displayed and only fields mentioned in views.py are shown.
(The object is persisted or a new object created from form data? shouldn't form have hidden fields then?)
Object is first searched with edited PK and then modified or created??

Comment: >>> Object is first searched with edited PK and then modified or created??
yes, how other way it will find? Why do you need name as pk anyway?

Comment: I thought it might have been searched with the older PK, and then a query would have been shot that would have updated the record with the new PK. I don't exactly need it. Just checking the generic views of django. I guess making PK editable is not a good design choice in any scenario. Better make Name unique rather than it being the PK

Comment: Making name just unique is much better, you're correct.

Answer (score 2):

For future visitors - I experienced the same issue, but did not have an editable primary key.  In my case I reused a form for both CreateView and UpdateView and forgot to allow for the difference in form action:

```
<form role="form" class="form-horizontal" action="{% url createobject' %}" method="post" multipart/form-data">
```

But it should have been

```
{% if not object %}
<form role="form" class="form-horizontal" action="{% url 'object:createobject' %}" method="post" multipart/form-data">
{% else %}
<form role="form" class="form-horizontal" action="{% url 'object:updateobject' object.pk %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% endif %}
```

So, whenever I submitted the form, the action called my Createview instead of my UpdateView.